# Why doesn't my function save my assignment?

Tags: r, function, random, subset, assign

```
f1 <- function(x) {
   zx1 <- sample(1:nrow(zone4[[x]]), nrow(zone4[[x]]), replace=F)
   zone4[[x]]$randnums <- zx1
}

f1(1)

## DOESN'T UPDATE zone4[[1]]

zx2 <- sample(1:nrow(zone4[[1]]), nrow(zone4[[1]]), replace=F)

zone4[[1]]$randnums <- zx2

## DOES UPDATE zone[[1]]
```

If I make a function f1() like shown above, the object 'zone4[[x]]' is not updated. However, if I run the same command as above but explicitly state 'x', as shown below, then the object 'zone4[[x]]' is updated. Why could this be? I want to know because I want to run iterations of the code. If within the definition of the function f1() above I write "names(zone4[[x]])", then the output I get tells me that the function did what it was supposed to, but when queried again, zone[[x]] appears to be unchanged. Thank you for your help. The idea is to make random numbers for each subset of a data set for a given year and another variable, zone. The data set was originally a single data frame, but I used the split() function to separate the data according to year and zone, of which there are 4. Maybe there is a better way to assign random numbers to specific subsets of data without using the split() function?

Comment: did you forget to finish your title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R` functions don't usually have side effects (ie. changing things in global objects)

This is a good thing (most of the time as we don't want unintended consequences)

The idiomatic approach is to assign the results to a new object (it can be the same name to overwrite the original)

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  zx1 <- sample(1:nrow(zone4[[x]]), nrow(zone4[[x]]), replace=F)
  zone4[[x]]$randnums <- zx1
  # usually a good idea to return the complete object
  # especially when a replacement function (in your case `[[<-`)
  # is the last one called
  return(zone4)
}

zone4 <- f1(1)
```

An alternative would be to use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
zone4 <- lapply(zone4, as.data.table)

f1 <- function(x) {
  zone4[[x]][,randnums := sample(.N)]
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

Comment: zone4 <- f1(1)
    # this ends up only putting the list of random numbers into zone4. When I try to run the function for more than one value of x at one time I get "recursive indexing failed at level 3".

Comment: @user2184368 -- please give an example of what `zone4` looks like. Which function are your refering to?

Comment: @mnel: what if it's a row/column/slice of a larger data structure?